# Swift ui picker with empty array No exact matches in call to initializer

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, foreach, swiftui

[image]

I have the following problem I have an array at the beginning empty `[]`

Then later it will be filled if certain things happen.

Anyway, as soon as I start the program I get the following error.

Can anyone help me out?

```swift
@State var userArray = []

if(userArray.count > 0) {
   Picker("", selection: $user) {
          ForEach(userArray, id: \.self) {
            Text($0)
          }
   }.labelsHidden()
}
```

Comment: Does your `userArray` array hold and array of a custom class, or `String`?

Comment: Array of strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly stating what objects you will be storing in `userArray`, in your case change

```
@State var userArray = []
```

to

```
@State var userArray: [String] = []

or

@State var userArray = [String]()
```

If you don't explicitly state what you are going to store in a `@State` variable. Swift will automatically set the data type as `Any`

Refer the examples I have shown below. The first is before stating the data type, while the second is after I set the data type

1. This is before explicitly stating what I will be storing on `userArray`
   [image]
2. After explicitly stating that I will be storing an array of strings (`[String]`)

[image]

Comment: Thx, but on the inside I had tried to do a similar thing if I remember
`Text($0 as! String)` It tightened, but it didn't work.

Comment: Doing that would make it unnecessarily complex